# Where do I attach the ground wire from a 3.5mm audio cable?

Tags: amplifier, raspberry-pi

I have a 3.5mm audio cable coming from a raspberry pi with wires exposed at the other end. I've soldered the positive and negative wires to the inputs of an amplifier board that I bought on eBay. There is no ground connector on the board. Where should I solder the audio ground wire on the amp board? Should it be connected to the negative power terminal on the amp board? Currently, there is a lot of white noise when I power up the amp.
[image: audio cable]
[image: amp board]

Comment: what do you mean by `positive and negative wires`?

Comment: Red and black are probably left and right.

Comment: We don't know what amplifier board that is and what does the manual say how to connect the input. Please provide further information to answer your question.

Answer (score 4):

That's a [mono (1 channel) amplifier](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/ANGEEK-TPA3118-Digital-Amplifier-Arduino/dp/B07KQDKVLC). You'll need two if you want stereo. If those are stereo wires, you have probably mislabeled them: red and black are right and left signals ("+"), the bare wire is the return ("ground" or "-").

Comment: Thanks, so if I understand you correctly, I would need to split my audio cable into two so that I had two sets of red, black, and ground wire. I would then solder the red wire to one the positive input of a mono board and the ground wire to the negative input. I would then also solder the black wire to the positive input of a second mono board and its corresponding ground wire to the negative input. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @forgetso Yes, but you don't necessarily need to split the R & L conductors, since each only goes to one place. Just make sure the ground is connected to both, the closer the better. You may also want to read up on the subject of ground loops, in case you run into an issue there (depends how the two boards and the source are powered).

Comment: check the info with the board. The - input is likely NOT ground if that is a TPA3116 (which has a differential input). It wants to be copnnected to SIGNAL ground. Probably there are decoupling caps on the board, in which case you can use the PSU neagtive.

Comment: Thanks @TypeIA, that clears things up somewhat. I had noise issues running the pi from a 12V-5V buck converter from the same PSU as the amps so I have switched to 2 power sources for now. @danmcb the [specs](https://components101.com/modules/tpa3118-mono-amplifier-module) state `Power In (GND/-) 4.5v-24v DC power Ground`. This reads to me that I should use the PSU negative connector as ground.

Comment: @forgetso most likely. But I would lookup the pin of the - input of the TDA chip and make sure they included a DC block cap at the input with a multimeter. Just to be sure.

Comment: @danmcb just looking at the board photo I don't see any coupling capacitors. At least if there is, it's a small package ceramic which would really be a shame. I don't think this is a problem though. Ground loops may be, especially if using independent power sources.

Comment: they will be small ceramic caps most likely if this is an ebay board. But check for sure with a meter.

Comment: I'm very new to electronics. How would I go about testing this? Do I check for resistance between the power input pin of the TPA3118 chip and the power input of the overall PCB? There are [lots of data sheets for these chips](https://www.alldatasheet.com/view.jsp?Searchword=TPA3118) and they all vary slightly. The power supplies are usually pin 18 and 19 however.